# Как уменьшить расстояние между дивами?

Tags: css, magento

[image: картинка]

css min-height: 157px; не присвоена строка, он образовывается автоматически, как понимаю с помощью ява скирпа js. Как мне уменьшить расстояние между дивами? Кусок кода, который как мне кажется отвечает за вычисление прилагаю. Откуда-то берётся промежуток в 15px нигде не прописанный. А так как цифра генерируется сама, то предположил, что дело в скрипте.
[ссылка на тестовый сайт](http://agestor.com/catalog.html?dir=asc&mode=grid&order=position)

```html
function decorateTable(table, options) {
    var table = $(table);
    if (table) {
        // set default options
        var _options = {
            'tbody'    : false,
            'tbody tr' : ['odd', 'even', 'first', 'last'],
            'thead tr' : ['first', 'last'],
            'tfoot tr' : ['first', 'last'],
            'tr td'    : ['last']
        };
        // overload options
        if (typeof(options) != 'undefined') {
            for (var k in options) {
                _options[k] = options[k];
            }
        }
        // decorate
        if (_options['tbody']) {
            decorateGeneric(table.select('tbody'), _options['tbody']);
        }
        if (_options['tbody tr']) {
            decorateGeneric(table.select('tbody tr'), _options['tbody tr']);
        }
        if (_options['thead tr']) {
            decorateGeneric(table.select('thead tr'), _options['thead tr']);
        }
        if (_options['tfoot tr']) {
            decorateGeneric(table.select('tfoot tr'), _options['tfoot tr']);
        }
        if (_options['tr td']) {
            var allRows = table.select('tr');
            if (allRows.length) {
                for (var i = 0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
                    decorateGeneric(allRows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD'), _options['tr td']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Set "odd", "even" and "last" CSS classes for list items
 * @see decorateGeneric()
 */
function decorateList(list, nonRecursive) {
    if ($(list)) {
        if (typeof(nonRecursive) == 'undefined') {
            var items = $(list).select('li')
        }
        else {
            var items = $(list).childElements();
        }
        decorateGeneric(items, ['odd', 'even', 'last']);
    }
}

/**
 * Set "odd", "even" and "last" CSS classes for list items
 * @see decorateGeneric()
 */
function decorateDataList(list) {
    list = $(list);
    if (list) {
        decorateGeneric(list.select('dt'), ['odd', 'even', 'last']);
        decorateGeneric(list.select('dd'), ['odd', 'even', 'last']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше бы все-таки url посмотреть... Что если Вы ошиблись, и это не тот "кусок кода"...

Comment: весь приведенный Вами код ссылается на функцию `decorateGeneric`, которой тут нет. Но, как мне кажется, функция лишь присваивает классы элементам каталога. Но вчисление высоты идет как-то иначе... Вобщем, дайте URL - так легче будет

Comment: [ссылка](http://agestor.com/catalog.html?dir=asc&mode=grid&order=position)

Comment: Убрал margin: 5px для наименования, и из вычисляемой суммы отнялось 5px, оставшиеся 10 не могу найти...

Comment: Высота блока товара (`.item`) 312 пикселей.  
Нижний блок с ценой и кнопкой (`.actions`) прилеплен к нижнему краю блока, а сам имеет фиксированную высоту, потому что кнопка и цена одинаковой высоты везде.

Найдите, где вычисляется высота блолка `.item`

Comment: Вычисляется высота "product-info", найти как к сожалению затрудняюсь, по идее это скрипт делает... Все элементы в этом блоке имеют свою высоту, только между наименованием и блоком action промежуток потому, что один к верху приклеен, другой книзу. Но ровно 10px как-то добавляется к общей высоте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл `/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js`.
Ищите строчку `var actionSpacing = 10;` (это где-то ближе к концу).
Замените на нужное кол-во пикселей. и Будет Вам счастье :)

Насолько я понимаю, это особенности выбранного Вами скина.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!!! Скажите, пожалуйста, как вы посмотрели, что эта строка отвечает за нужное действие и где она находилась?

Comment: :) ну как.. просто открыл этот файл `app.js` и в нем нашел все упоминания `product-info` и проанализировал окружающий код. Плюс там еще комментари стоят.